# passing a string to an intent kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Why am I getting a null string through Intent even after passing the value?

MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding=ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        binding.btnFirst.setOnClickListener {
            val name=binding.etName.text.toString()
            Intent(this,SecondActivity::class.java).also{
                it.putExtra("EXTRA_NAME",name)
                startActivity(it)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

SecondActivity

```
class SecondActivity:AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivitySecondBinding
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding= ActivitySecondBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val name=intent.getStringArrayExtra("EXTRA_NAME")
        val toPrint="$name hahahaha"

        binding.tvNameIntent.text=toPrint

    }
}
```

toPrint is getting "null hahahaha"

Can someone please rectify my error?

Answer (score 3):

You are putting in a `String` so you should be also reading a `String` and not `StringArray`. You can use e.g. `getStringExtra()` for that.

Answer (score 0):

val name=intent.getStringArrayExtra("EXTRA_NAME") should be changed to
val name=intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_NAME")